# Selenium IEDriver Not Successfully Clicking Link

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I’m seeing some very strange behaviour from the IE driver for Selenium.

I progress right through a registration of a user workflow, at the end of which I would like the automated test to click the log off link.

I have employed the following code to that end:

```
public virtual void LogOff()
{
    SeleniumTestDriver.FindByPartialLinkText(Constants.LogoffLinkText).Click();
}

public IWebElement FindByPartialLinkText(string linkTextToFind)
{
    var linkWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WaitTimeout));
    return linkWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.PartialLinkText(linkTextToFind)));
}
```

The bit that I find weird is the fact that the link is visible on the screen. I can see it, for the whole duration of the wait period. It seems to be flickering.

I have confirmed that the link is in fact a link, and not a button styled to look like a link.

Using Selenium v2.41.0
IE 11
IEDriver v2.41.1

As further info, it works perfectly in Firefox.

Am I using Selenium incorrectly?

Comment: How about a link to the page, or code snipped of the page?

Comment: Can you share the HTML code of the link (along with the parent tag of the link) to understand / debug the issue.

Comment: @SiKing The link is <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">&nbsp;&nbsp;[Log Off]</a> . Would be interesting to know if there is something problematic with that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using sendkeys() instead of click(). This has worked without any issues in IE for me.

```
SeleniumTestDriver.FindByPartialLinkText(Constants.LogoffLinkText).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: This is a workaround, not really a solution. The user more than likely clicks an element rather than tabbing to and pressing enter on the element. Unfortunately I've no better solution, therefore there isn't a lot I'm adding here other than clarifying.